# Can multiple Spring @Repository classes be multi-threaded?

Tags: spring, multithreading, jpa

I am working on a multi-threaded Spring Boot/JPA/Hibernate project started by someone else. They have created 10 DAO classes and each one looks something like this:

```
@Repository
public class FirstDAO
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    ...
}
```

I am working on learning JPA & Hibernate, so I know the entity managers can persist different versions of the same data.

When we have that many DAO classes, are there other pitfalls we need to worry about? Thx!

Edit:
Since I am pretty new with JPA and multi-threading, I am mostly just nervous.
But a question I have is: if you want more than one @Repository for a database then do you have to create an interface that has the @PersistenceContext and then you implement the interface multiple times?

Comment: 10 is really not that many. It's actual quite a tiny number. And whether you have 1 or 10 DAOs doesn't change anything to how you write your DAOs. You ask about what "other" pitfalls to worry about. But what is the pitfall you're concerned with in the first place?

Comment: This pretty much answers my question... The pitfall I mention is that if you have multiple persisted entity managers, they can both persist the same data. So, if you do a read operation on the persisted data instead of directly from the database then your data is not thread safe. So, I am worried there are other things that I need to be aware of.

Comment: The question in the edit doesn't make much sense: interfaces don't have fields. So you can't have an interface with a field annotated with PersistenceContext. The code posted in the question is perfectly fine.

Comment: Entities returned by the entityManager inside the transaction running on a thread are distinct from entities returned by the entityManager in another transaction running on a different thread (even if both have the same ID and the same type). Entities are not (and should not) be shared between threads. They are indeed not thread-safe, but it's not a problem because they're not shared between threads.

Comment: OK. I will take out the edit. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.... D'oh, I should have remembered that you cannot have fields or annotations on interfaces.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand much better. I did not know that threads do not share entity managers. TYVM!